# Why does the first column of a XamDataGrid have two LabelPresenters?

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a `XamDataGrid` (version 13.2) where I subscribe to the LabelPresenters' `SizeChanged` events. When the grid first loads, two `SizeChanged` events are thrown for the first `Field`'s `LabelPresenter`. After doing some digging, I found that the two events are for two different instances of `LabelPresenters`.

I'm trying to access the `ActualWidth` of `LabelPresenter`, but for one of the events, the value of this property is not what I expect. For example, one `LabelPresenter`'s value be 40.0 (which matches up with what's shown on screen), while another will show as 166.0.

When I look into the visual tree with Snoop, it only shows the `LabelPresenters` for the Fields that are displayed, which is what I would expect.

Sample XAML:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid BindToSampleData="True" Name="xamDataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:LabelPresenter}">
            <EventSetter Event="SizeChanged" Handler="OnLabelPresenterSizeChanged"/>
        </Style>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

Sample C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Dictionary<LabelPresenter, Field> labelPresenters = new Dictionary<LabelPresenter, Field>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLabelPresenterSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelPresenter lp = sender as LabelPresenter;
        labelPresenters.Add(lp, lp.Field);

        Debug.WriteLine("Field count: {0} LabelPresenter Count: {1}", xamDataGrid1.FieldLayouts[0].Fields.Count, labelPresenters.Count);
    }
```

You can see 5 `LabelPresenters` in the dictionary, even though four fields exist in the grid.

What Snoop shows
[image: What Snoop shows]
[image]

How can I filter out or ignore this extra `LabelPresenter` during `SizeChanged` events?

Comment: did you post this in the infragistics forums?

Comment: Infragistics no longer allows you to post on their forums without a current subscription, so I'm trying here before shelling out for a new subscription.

Comment: First may be for the RowHeader's Column Header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By digging into the visual tree at runtime, I was able to find that the extra `LabelPresenter` is a child of a `CellPlaceholder` object. The [documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2013.2/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter_namespace.html) for it states only that it is for internal use only, so I really don't know what it's for.

By ignoring this `LabelPresenter` (and only checking the visual tree for Fields whose `ActualPosition.Column` property has a value of 0), I can filter out the erroneous `ActualWidth` values in my logic.